# how to share mp4 video on facebook without secure_url is it possible?

Tags: facebook

The Open Graph tags in this case look like this:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="facebookid" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site_name">
<meta property="og:url content="http://example.com/pages/10" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="detail" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:video:url" content="http://example.com/video.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
```

Is there a way to let the video play without secure_url or secure_url required for it?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

Because the Facebook website is loaded via HTTPS, all content that gets embedded into it needs to be loaded via HTTPS as well – otherwise the browser will block it as “mixed content.”

---

An SSL certificate doesn’t have to be “expensive” any more these days. With LetsEncrypt you can generate a certificate yourself and for free.

If that’s not an option on your hosting platform, then you could try StartSSL, they provide free basic certificates as well.

But your server must allow you to upload/embed a certificate for your domain. If you are not clear on what your options are, check your hoster’s FAQ and/or ask their support.

Comment: Thanks but if we using player (.swf file) then also we need secure_url because as you say facebook website is loaded via https?

Comment: Yes, of course you do. It doesn’t matter that it’s flash – it is external content embedded into a secure website, and therefor it must be served over HTTPS as well.